# Laravel Route [events_page] not defined. error

Tags: laravel, laravel-route

I'm still making my events page, yet another error. I'm making an archive function and I've setup the route correctly, however now that I've created the "events_archive" route, "events_page" for some reason is playing up and throwing this error: `Route [events_page] not defined.`. It was all working until I made the archive route, do I have to make the controller function and then the error will fix?

Thanks.

Comment: please share your route and some functional code to help you

Comment: `Route::get('events/', 'Events\EventsController@index')->name('events_page');
Route::get('events/', 'Events\EventsController@archive')->name('events_archive');`

I haven't started making the function.

Comment: do you have `Group route prefix` top of this roure ?

Comment: you are giving different name to same route `events/`, change the method or give it a new route `events/archive`.

Answer (score 1):

You routes have duplicate URI `'events/'`

```
Route::get('events/', 'Events\EventsController@index')->name('events_page');
Route::get('events/', 'Events\EventsController@archive')->name('events_archive');
```

Make sure to make them unique such as:

```
Route::get('events/', 'Events\EventsController@index')->name('events_page');
Route::get('events_archive/', 'Events\EventsController@archive')->name('events_archive');
```